# What's causing this to program crash with MySQL Connector C++?

Tags: c++, mysql, linux

I've got a simple code block where I attempt to access a local database to alter and query a database table. I'm connecting to the host successfully, can query integer values successfully, and otherwise fairly sanguine about how things are coming along.  The problem arises when I try to read a value from a column of the table via `sql::ResultSet::GetString()`.  The program simply terminates after the first call to this function.

I've got a possible breadcrumb for finding the cause of this problem: I had to use `sql::PreparedStatement` instead of `sql::Statement` because of a problem where every call to `sql::Statement::execute(string)` produced the same behavior.  Is there a problem with the SQLString->string mapping?  I'm at a total loss here and any help would be appreciated.

I'm writing this code in Eclipse Helios CDT with the appropriate .so set, in CentOS 5.5.

**Edit:** I've tested the code below without the call to sql::ResultSet::getString() and the output is as follows:

```
Starting MySQLTest 
Id: 1
Id: 2
Id: 3
Id: 10
Id: 222
Id: 333
MySQLTest Exiting...
```

The table looks like:

```
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| name  | char(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.13 sec)
```

With the current state being:

```
+------+--------+
| id   | name   |
+------+--------+
|    1 | FIRST  | 
|    2 | SECOND | 
|    3 | THIRD  | 
|   10 | JUMP   | 
|  222 | TEST   | 
|  333 | TEST3  | 
+------+--------+
```

Output in the console is:

```
Starting MySQLTest 
Id: 1
Name: FIRST
```

The source is included below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

#include <stdlib.h>

//MySQL connection headers

#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/connection.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>
#include <cppconn/prepared_statement.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/metadata.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset_metadata.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/warning.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Starting MySQLTest \n";
    try
    {
        sql::Driver *driver;
        sql::Connection *connection;
        sql::PreparedStatement *prepStatement;
        sql::ResultSet *result;

        //Attempt to create a connection
        driver = get_driver_instance();
        connection = driver->connect("HOST", "USER", "PASS");
        connection->setSchema("testdb");

        prepStatement = connection->prepareStatement("insert into testtable(id, name) values(333, 'TEST3')");
        prepStatement->execute();
        prepStatement = connection->prepareStatement("select * from testtable");
        result = prepStatement->executeQuery();

        while(result->next())
        {
            cout << "Id: " << result->getInt("id") << "\n";
                    //TERMINATE AFTER THE FOLLOWING LINE
            cout << "Name: " << result->getString("name") << "\n";
        }

        delete result;
        delete connection;
    }
    catch(sql::SQLException &e)
    {
cout << e.what() << "\n";
    }

    cout << "MySQLTest Exiting...";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not testing the return values from functions? Every time you call an API you should test its return value, and issue a diagnostic to yourself  if nobody else if it fails.

Comment: @Neil: A perfectly valid point.  I threw this together intending for it to be a basic "proof of concept" that the library calls were working and I hadn't bothered to flesh anything out.

Comment: what do you see when you step-in with the debugger?

Comment: @Mike: Stepping into the getString() function, you see the declaration:   `SQLString(const char other[]) : realStr(other) {}` where `realStr` is defined as a `std::string`.

Comment: Need more information, such as the table structure.  Type `describe testtable;" into the MySql console.  Edit your post with the new information.

Comment: @Thomas: Updated with table description.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use prepared statements for your needs.  I'm using SQL statements for string fields and don't use prepared statements.  I only use prepared statements for BLOBs.

Take the text that you are sending to the database and paste them into a MySQL console.  I believe that you will find that you are not using the `select` and the prepared statement correctly, especially in retrieving the data.

In my program, I construct an SQL `SELECT` statement by applying a *visitor* to each field in the record.  Here's a sample of my code:

```
       insert_visitor.begin(rid);
       rid.accept_visitor(insert_visitor);
       insert_visitor.end();
       std::string             insertion_sql_text;
       insertion_sql_text += insert_visitor.get_query();
       std::cout << "\n" << insertion_sql_text << std::endl;
       sql::Connection *       p_db_connection(get_db_connection());
       boost::scoped_ptr<sql::Statement>               sql_stmt(p_db_connection->createStatement());
       if (!sql_stmt)
       {
               break;
       }
       try
       {
               sql_stmt->execute(insertion_sql_text);
       }
       catch (sql::SQLException exception)
       {
               wxLogDebug("SQL Exception thrown for executing: \"%s\"",
                                       insertion_sql_text.c_str());
       }

       //-------------------------------------------------------------
       //      Retrieve the new value of the auto incremented ID field.
       //-------------------------------------------------------------
       int new_id = -1;
       boost::scoped_ptr<sql::ResultSet>               query_results(sql_stmt->executeQuery("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()"));
       query_results->next();
       new_id = query_results->getInt(1);
       rid.set_record_id(new_id);
```

where `rid` is my record.

### Edit 1:

Definitely type in your statements into the console.  This will show you the output (record) from the database, which could be different that what you think you are getting.

See also [MySQL Prepared Statement Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)

Comment: I switched back to sql::Statement to no avail.  I've got no problem retrieving the integer results of the query, as I'll update in my post above.  There's something tricky about the getString() call.

Comment: @Rich Hoffman:  Have you tried using a numerical index instead of the field name?  In my code, I am using the field index rather than the name.